Neural prophet make_future_dataframe produces dataframe with incorrect frequency
Issue: Not able to pass in 'freq' argument to make_future_dataframe of Neural prophet. Without 'freq' argument, Neural Prophet produces future dataframe of daily frequency instead of weekly frequency. Below is the code:

df=train_fp.copy()
print(df)
    
params =  dict(
        growth='off',
        yearly_seasonality=True,
        weekly_seasonality=False,
        daily_seasonality=False,
        batch_size=64,
        epochs=200,
        learning_rate=0.03)

    
m = NeuralProphet(**params,quantiles=[0.90, 0.10]) if params is not None else NeuralProphet()
m.set_plotting_backend("plotly-static")
 
future_np = m.make_future_dataframe(df, periods=61*5)
print(future_np)


expectation: dataframe future_np should have W-SUN frequency (since df has weekly frequency)
actuals : dataframe future_np has daily frequency. If freq argument is included in make_future_dataframe, for example: future_df = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=50, freq="W-SUN"), NeuralProphet throws error 'TypeError: NeuralProphet.make_future_dataframe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'
Actual output looks like below

INFO - (NP.df_utils._infer_frequency) - Major frequency W-SUN corresponds to 99.363% of the data.
INFO - (NP.df_utils._infer_frequency) - Dataframe freq automatically defined as W-SUN
INFO - (NP.df_utils.return_df_in_original_format) - Returning df with no ID column
            ds         y
0   2019-12-29   12424.0
1   2020-01-05   20213.0
2   2020-01-12   22507.0
3   2020-01-19   18660.0
4   2020-01-26   18155.0
..         ...       ...
152 2022-11-27  332487.0
153 2022-12-04  144574.0
154 2022-12-11  179180.0
155 2022-12-18  114382.0
156 2022-12-25   60278.0

[157 rows x 2 columns]
            ds     y
0   2022-12-26  None
1   2022-12-27  None
2   2022-12-28  None
3   2022-12-29  None
4   2022-12-30  None
..         ...   ...
300 2023-10-22  None
301 2023-10-23  None
302 2023-10-24  None
303 2023-10-25  None
304 2023-10-26  None

[305 rows x 2 columns]

